# Oracle Cloud Infra connection between instances not working

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I have two instances in Oracle Cloud Infra. Both running Ubuntu 20.4. I have very strange problem. I cannot access Apache on instance 1 from 2 or even from public IP. Both instances are part of same Subnet. I have enable traffic from Security list, NSG. I can ping and SSH but just can't access apache page on port 80

```
ubuntu@docker1:~$ ping 10.100.246.237
PING 10.100.246.237 (10.100.246.237) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.100.246.237: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.410 ms
64 bytes from 10.100.246.237: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.662 ms
^C
--- 10.100.246.237 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1022ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.410/0.536/0.662/0.126 ms
ubuntu@docker1:~$ curl http://10.100.246.237
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 10.100.246.237 port 80: No route to host
ubuntu@docker1:~$
```

Instance 1 Docker1 = 10.100.246.50
Instance 2 Docker2 = 10.100.246.237

I tried using Oracle Linux but still same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to open the port 80 in your firewall on your Ubuntu instances.
By default Ubuntu comes with [UFW (Uncomplicated Firewall)](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW) so you can open the port with something like this : `sudo ufw allow 80/tcp`.

Oracle Linux uses [firewalld](https://docs.oracle.com/en/operating-systems/oracle-linux/8/firewall/ol-firewall.html#ol-firewall-sec).